# text-align right div + add padding-right without altering div width?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that looks like this:

```
<div style="width: 400px; height: 50px; text-align: right; padding-right: 50px">This is a test</div>
```

I need the text to have some space at the right, so I added `padding-right: 50px`. Then I notice the padding, but now the `div` is 450px instead of the original 400px.

How can I add those 50px of padding without altering the width of the div?

It would need to work in most major browsers. I've seen several examples, but they don't seem to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline styling, as requested:

```html
<div style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 400px; height: 50px; text-align: right; padding-right: 50px; background: green">This is a test</div>
```

For CSS elsewhere:

```
*, :before, :after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with CSS. Can this be added within the `style` in the div?

Comment: I added it to the style and it worked: `<div style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 400px; ...`

Comment: Yes, it works with inline styling. I added a snippet to show that it does. The background is to show the dimensions of the div, which you can remove.